# Analysis of “Finding Maximum Sum of Subsequent Elements” algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sequences, arrays

If possible, I would like someone to give an analytic explanation of the algorithm.

For example, given the sequence

```
-2, 4, -1, 3, 5, -6, 1, 2
```

the maximum subsequence sum would be

```
4 + -1 + 3 + 5 = 11
```

This algorithm I am reffering to is an divide and cconquer type algorithm.

The algorithm is *O(nlogn)* complexity.

Actually i seek to see an example of all the steps that this algorithm produces. The above sequence could be used for the example.

Comment: Do you mean finding the maximum _contiguous subsequence_ sum? The maximum subset sum is trivial: toss out all the negative elements.

Comment: No i mean maximum sum of subsequent elements

Comment: [Try this.](http://algos.tnsatish.com/2010/08/finding-maximum-subset-sum.html)

Comment: @Peter - That's just more code. OP wants an analysis of it's complexity.

Comment: An analytic example using the sequence i give above will do.

Comment: @Ted: Thanks!  I didn't get that from first (or second reading)... though I suppose I should have inferred he wasn't after code from "I've seen the code".

Comment: There is no need to add "plz" and "I want" in the title. If you are clear and write a well structured question nice answers will come.

Comment: ok missingno ill have that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to split your sequence in half, find the answers for both halves, then use that to find the answer for the entire sequence.

Assume you have a sequence `[left, right]`. Let `m = (left + right) / 2`. Now, the maximum sum subsequence (`MSS`) of `[left, right]` is either `MSS(left, m)`, `MSS(m + 1, right)` or a sequence that starts in `[left, m]` and ends somewhere in `[m + 1, right]`.

Pseudocode:

```
MSS(left, right)
  if left = right then return sequence[left]
  m = (left + right) / 2
  leftMSS = MSS(left, m)
  rightMSS = MSS(m + 1, right)

  maxLeft = -inf // find the maximum sum subsequence that ends with m and starts with at least left
  cur = 0
  i = m
  while i >= left do
    cur += sequence[i]
    if cur > maxLeft
      maxLeft = cur

  maxRight = -inf // find the maximum sum subsequence that starts with m + 1 and ends with at most right
  cur = 0
  i = m + 1
  while i <= right
    cur += sequence[i]
    if cur > maxRight
      maxRight = cur

  return max(leftMSS, rightMSS, maxLeft + maxRight)
```

This is `O(n log n)` because the recursion three has height `O(log n)` and at each level of the tree we do `O(n)` work.

Here is how it would run on `-2, 4, -1, 3, 5, -6, 1, 2`:

```
 0  1  2 3 4  5 6 7
-2  4 -1 3 5 -6 1 2

                                             MSS(0, 7) = 11
                                      /                    \
                              MSS(0, 3) = 6                 MSS(4, 7) = 5 ------
                          /                  \              |                   \
           MSS(0, 1) = 4                    MSS(2, 3) = 3   MSS(4, 5) = 5      NSS(6, 7) = 3
             /       \                    /              \
   MSS(0, 0) = -2     MSS(1, 1) = 4    MSS(2, 2) = -1    MSS(3, 3) = 3
```

Of interest is the computation of `MSS(0, 3)` and `MSS(0, 7)`, since these do not simply take the max of their children. For `MSS(0, 3)` we try to make as large a sum as possible adding consecutive elements starting with the middle of the interval (1) and going left. This max is `4`. Next we do the same starting with the middle of the interval + 1 and going right. This max is `2`. Adding these together gets us a maximum sum subsequence with the sum of `6`, which is larger than the maximum sum subsequence of the two child intervals, so we take this one instead.

The reasoning is similar for `MSS(0, 7)`.

Comment: Nail in the head. My mistake was that as i was computing the values for the base cases i was eliminating some values but i shouldnt have done that as it seems.tnx

Answer (score 2):

This can actually be done in O(n) time using an algorithm called [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).  I have written up [my own version and an analysis of its complexity](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=kadane) if you're interested.  The idea is to use dynamic programming to incrementally improve a solution until an optimal subsequence can be found.

Comment: I know that O(n)(as well as O(n^2)and O(n^3) also exist)exist, but today i was studying the O(nlogn) algo so i need an example for that particular algo.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Right now it seems like you're begging for the answer without doing any of your own work.  I can provide the analysis, but I'm not going to do so unless I have a guarantee that I'm not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: No homework. I am independently researching for my own interest algorithms ,discrete math and stuff.I am self motivated. I stuck for this thing now all day long.I don't want to see the analysis because i found many sources for that. But i didn't found a single example of the steps on an actual sequence

Comment: Perhaps if you pointed us to the specific algorithm you want to see analyzed, someone could point you to an analysis. :)

Comment: @Ted Hopp Here www.cs.ru.nl/~chaack/teaching/CIS500s00/Transpar/trans15.pdf    On page 4 you can see this algorithm